choose an empty folder from the client system for an offline website
I need to choose an empty folder from my client system for an offline website to work in the Local Server - IIS. I attempted to use the FileUpload control, but it did not work when selecting an empty folder.
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileFolder" Style="display: none" runat="server" webkitdirectory  directory/>
    string filename = Server.MapPath(FileFolder.PostedFile.FileName);
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filename);
    txtprojectFolder.Text=  fileInfo.DirectoryName;


You can create a new empty folder as long as it is in the folder the website is running in.

For reasons of secuirty, use of the file upload control does not support, send, show or give use of the path name of a file when using the up-load control. This is for security reasons. So, the browser NEVER sends the local path name to the server when using a FileUpLoad control. Only the file name is available , and information about what kind of computer, or folders existing client side are not available from the browser side. I would suggest that if you need some folders for a user, then the server code can create such a folder - but you CAN NOT select a folder with the browser at all
